# Format mnemonic code to date, i.e. "2016m2" to "Feb-16"

Tags: excel, date, date-formatting

I have a list of months in mnemonic code which I'd like to convert/format to dates in excel.

Here's a list of examples:

```
2016m1 = Jan-16
2016m2 = Feb-16
2016m3 = Mar-16
```

I used the standard date formatting option in excel but it did nothing. Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Have you tried writing some VBA to convert it?

Comment: No, ideally i'd like it handled without using VBA, if possible.

Comment: Well you could probably write a regular formula, but that would likely end up less readable (IMO). Have you tried *that*?

Comment: @Boosted_d16: so show us what you've tried to do with standard functions, and where you got stuck...

Comment: @Boosted_d16: how many years do you have to handle? if you only have a few years, then brute-force search-and-replace or translation will be fastest and simplest. Perhaps edit your example to illustrate the full range of possible values.

Comment: @smci: I right clicked on the cells and selected several formatting options available. I used yyyy-mm in the custom category but didnt achieve anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: nope, didn't try that. How would that even work?

Comment: @Boosted_d16: because that input is not a date, it's a string. Use an Excel formula on the substrings: left-4-characters (the year part) and rightmost-1-or-2-characters-after-the-m (the month part)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=DATE(LEFT(A1,4),SUBSTITUTE(A1,LEFT(A1,5),""),1)
```

You can then apply your own date format to the cell.

Comment: Excellent! thanks a lot. Wouldve taken me a long time to crack this.

Comment: +1 for forming a date and formatting/presenting it as required, rather than generating a string that sorts incorrectly.